# how to combine db4o and android intents

Tags: android, android-intent, db4o

I'm making (my first) android application and I'm a little bit puzzled with the use of db4o.

I have one activity in which I have a listView, and let the user select an object. Then I pass this object trough a series of intents to other activities (to populate its fields) and then back to the main activity.

But the problem is, when I pass an object (it is serializable), the object I get out of the intent is not the same as the one I put in. (different id, when I check with debug).
All the fields are the same, but it's just not 'the same' object.

So when I try to store the updated object in the db4o, it doesn't recognize it, and stores a double.

I've figured out two workarounds:

- Also pass an 'original/unmodified' object, and use it to get the db4o reference (through QBE), and then updating the fields of that object with the values of the changed object.
- Using global variables so I don't have to use intents (to pass the object)

But both seem really bad to me? What could be a real solution, instead of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a singleton to store your object and the fields that other classes (?) need to set so everyone has access. I'm not clear of your use of intents in this explanation.

Comment: Sample use scenario:

I have a list of objects in one activity. When I click on an object, I send an intent from the main-activity to another activity where I can edit the object. The object itself is sent along with the intent as a serializable extra; When I'm done editing I send the (now edited) object back to the main activity, where I save it. 

The 'singleton' approach is what I meant when I said 'using global variables' in my question. But it seems wrong to do this for this kind of situation?

Comment: If you want to pass through your intents, make a class that holds the info and pass that instead. A singleton isn't like the old global variables, it is a class that can only exist once. If it is a philosophical debate, it is a valid approach.

Comment: I've implemented the singleton approach; It's working great! thanks